# Add/update user_meta with checkbox in user settings Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to set some values in the user setting via a checkbox.
I add a custom checkbox for the user in `fuctions.php`

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'add_extra_info' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'add_extra_info' );

function add_extra_info( $user ) { ?>

    <tr>
        <th>
            Specialization
        </th>
        <?php
            $Specialization = esc_attr(get_the_author_meta('Specialization',$user->ID,true )); 
            $Specialization = array(
                array( 'id' => 'AAA', 'name' => 'Just a comment' )
            );
        ?>
        <td>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox"<?php if ($Specialization[0] == '1') { ?> checked="checked"<?php } ?>  name="Specialization[]" value="spec1"> Оффшоры и корпоративное право зарубежных государств 
            </label><br>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox"<?php if ($Specialization == '2') { ?> checked="checked"<?php } ?>  name="Specialization[]" value="spec2"> Фидуциарный сервис и трастовое право 
            </label><br>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox"<?php if ($Specialization == '3') { ?> checked="checked"<?php } ?>  name="Specialization[]" value="spec3"> Аудит иностранных компаний 
            </label><br>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox"<?php if ($Specialization == '4') { ?> checked="checked"<?php } ?>  name="Specialization[]" value="spec4"> Бухгалтерское сопровождение бизнеса за рубежом 
            </label><br>
        </td>
    </tr>

<?php } ?>
```

Use update_user_meta

```
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_info' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_info' );

function save_extra_info( $user_id ) {
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'Specialization', sanitize_text_field( 
    $_POST['Specialization[]'] ) );
}
```

How do I store parameters in an array? Also update and display in the user settings.

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding the `$specialization` array value before use.

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'add_extra_info' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'add_extra_info' );

function add_extra_info( $user ) { 
    $specialization = get_the_author_meta('specialization',$user->ID,true ); 
?>
    <table class="form-table" role="presentation">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Specialization</th>
                <td>
                    <p><label>
                        <input type="checkbox" <?php if( !empty( $specialization ) && in_array( 'spec1', $specialization  ) ) : ?> checked="checked" <?php endif; ?> name="specialization[]" value="spec1"> spec1
                    </label></p>
                    <p><label>
                        <input type="checkbox"  <?php if( !empty( $specialization ) && in_array( 'spec2', $specialization ) ) : ?> checked="checked" <?php endif; ?> name="specialization[]" value="spec2"> spec2 
                    </label></p>
                    <p><label>
                        <input type="checkbox"  <?php if( !empty( $specialization ) && in_array( 'spec3', $specialization ) ) : ?> checked="checked" <?php endif; ?> name="specialization[]" value="spec3"> spec3
                    </label></p>
                    <p><label>
                        <input type="checkbox"  <?php if( !empty( $specialization ) && in_array( 'spec4', $specialization ) ) : ?> checked="checked" <?php endif; ?> name="specialization[]" value="spec4"> spec4
                    </label></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<?php } 

add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_info' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_info' );

function save_extra_info( $user_id ) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) { return false; }

    $array = array_map( 'sanitize_text_field', wp_unslash( $_POST['specialization'] ) );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'specialization',  $array );
}
```